# Ajax call not working with Jquery 1.7.2?

Tags: ajax, jquery

After upgrading Jquery libraries from 1.4.4 to 1.7.2 this ajax call no longer enters the success function? Any suggestions? TIA

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    url: myURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        // add basic authorization
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    success: function (dataItem) {
        //Do success work 
    },
    complete: function (dataItem) {
        //Do complete work
    },
    error: function (dataItem) {
        //error message
    }
}); // end $.ajax
```

Comment: What is the error console saying? Can you put something in your `error` callback so you can see whether that gets triggered instead?

Comment: The error callback is being triggered.

Comment: Have you watched the request/response cycle in your console to see if you might get some additional clues?

Comment: Then output the error. The error callback accepts the following arguments: `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`

Comment: returns a transport error - the call works fine in a browser and with the old version. The only thing I found to work is noConflict(), this seems like a hack up job.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to update, why not update to newest version.

**This is How jQuery tell's you to fix it:**

We realize that existing sites and plugins may be affected by these changes, and are providing the jQuery Migrate plugin for a transitional upgrade path. Individual descriptions below indicate if the behavior changed in 1.9 can be restored by using the jQuery Migrate plugin. Note that all of the changes in jQuery 1.9 will also apply to jQuery 2.0, and the jQuery Migrate plugin will be usable there as well.

The uncompressed development version of the jQuery Migrate plugin includes console log output to warn when specific deprecated and/or removed features are being used. This makes it valuable as a migration debugging tool for finding and remediating issues in existing jQuery code and plugins. It can be used for its diagnostics with versions of jQuery core all the way back to 1.6.4.

The compressed version of the plugin does not generate any log output, and can be used on production sites when jQuery 1.9 or higher is desired but older incompatible jQuery code or plugins must also be used. Ideally this would only be used as a short-term solution, but that's a decision for you to make.

[LINK IS HERE](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)

**Other Options**

- Check with plugin developer to see if the plugin has been upgraded
- find a newer version of a plugin with the same or close features
- Update the plugin code yourself, by replacing depreciated code with relevant replacement code.

Comment: This does not help upgrading from 1.4 to 1.7, the problem here is obviously do to the $.ajax rewrite that happend in 1.5 which is not addressed by the migrate plugin. Chances are he'll have the same issue in 1.9

Comment: @ROY I don't control what version we update to. The migrate plugin sounds like a good idea but will not work in this instance.